# Are halogens a further classification of non-metals, or are they another group themselves?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-table

I've searched many pages in the internet, and many just classify halogens
(Grp 7A) as non-metals. However, my teacher classified them as another group in the periodic table, and when asked which groups are classified under non-metals, she written the correct answer to be group 3A-6A. I'm very confused as I thought non-metals include halogens?

Thanks in advance!!:)

Comment: You thought right.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So halogens are non-metals and are not another group?

Comment: That's right. There is no another group. Non-metals include every element which is not a metal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halogens are merely just a subset of non-metals. Consider this periodic table:

[image]

Clearly halogens do come under the fluoroscent colored elements, which signifies non-metals. There are several other groups, which have their own unique name. For instance, the oxygen group members are called **chalcogens**, and the nitrogen group members are called **pnictogens**.

However, there is something special about halogens though. They are infact the most non-metallic elements known, considering their great tendency to gain electrons. This also makes the halogen group the only group other than inert gases to have only non metals in them (ignoring Ununseptium of course).

In short, halogens are a subset of non-metals and not an entire class by themselves. But they are, the most important subset of non metals.